# flipbook unable to go backward in pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

Currently I'm trying to create my own flipbook from scratch. The flipbook works when going forward in pages but when going backwards, the flipbook either does not render the image at all or render it out of the margin.

I have tried to change the transition degree at the css file or change the JS function prevPg() but it wasn't really working.

```js
let maxPg = 11;
let x = 0;

function nextPg() {
  x++;
  console.log(x);

  let pageNo = document.getElementsByClassName('page');
  if (x >= 12) {
    alert('You are at the last page');
    x = 11;
  } else {
    pageNo[x - 1].classList.remove('flipped-bwd')
    pageNo[x - 1].classList.add('flipped-fwd')

    function close() {
      pageNo[x - 1].style.display = 'none';
    }
    setTimeout(close, 500);
  }
}

function prevPg() {
  console.log(x);
  let pageNo = document.getElementsByClassName('page');
  if (x < 1) {
    alert('You are at the first page');
    x = 0;
  } else {
    pageNo[x - 1].classList.remove('flipped-fwd');
    pageNo[x].style.removeProperty('display');
    pageNo[x - 1].classList.add('flipped-bwd');
    pageNo[x + 1].style.display = 'none'
  }
  x--;
}
```

```css
.page {
  perspective: 2000px;
  transition: transform 1.75s;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
}

.flipped-fwd {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform-origin: left;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: flex;
}

.flipped-bwd {
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="next" onclick="nextPg()"></div>
<div id="prev" onclick="prevPg()"></div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="p1" class="page" style="padding: 35px 0;">
    <img src="menu/1.png" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div id="p2" class="page" style="padding: 35px 0;">
    <img src="menu/2.png" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div id="p3" class="page" style="padding: 35px 0;">
    <img src="menu/3.png" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div id="p4" class="page" style="padding: 35px 0;">
    <img src="menu/4.png" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div id="p5" class="page" style="padding: 35px 0;">
    <img src="menu/5.png" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div id="p6" class="page" style="padding: 35px 0;">
    <img src="menu/6.png" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div id="p7" class="page" style="padding: 35px 0;">
    <img src="menu/7.png" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div id="p8" class="page" style="padding: 35px 0;">
    <img src="menu/8.png" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div id="p9" class="page" style="padding: 35px 0;">
    <img src="menu/9.png" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div id="p10" class="page" style="padding: 35px 0;">
    <img src="menu/10.png" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div id="p11" class="page" style="padding: 35px 0;">
    <img src="menu/11.png" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div id="p12" class="page" style="padding: 35px 0;">
    <img src="menu/12.png" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
</div>
```